# Need to convert nested Json response to csv in powershell

Tags: json, csv, powershell

I have below sample nested json response and I need to convert this response with specific values into CSV file. Below is the sample nested Json response:

```html
{
  "transaction": {
    "id": "TestTransID",
    "testCode": "NEW",
    "TestStatus": "SUCCESS",
    "client": {
      "TestNumber": "112112111"
    },
    "subject": {
      "individual": {
        "additionalAttributes": {
          "extraid": "787877878"
        },
        "addressList": [
          {
            "city": "New York",
            "country": {
              "name": "United States"
            },
            "postalCode": "123456789",
            "stateOrProvince": {
              "codeValue": "NY"
            }
          }
        ],
        "gender": "F",
        "identificationDocumentList": [
          {
            "number": "1214558520",
            "type": "TestId"
          }
        ],
        "name": {
          "firstName": "Qusay TestFull",
          "lastName": "TestLast",
          "middleName": "Middle 3"
        }
      }
    },
    "PROCESSConfiguration": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "testProductList": [
      {
        "product": {
          "id": 00,
          "name": "Test PROCESS",
          "productCode": "EFG",
          "disclaimer": "TestDisclaimer"
        },
        "testSourceResponseList": [
          {
            "testSource": {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "TEST"
            },
            "testSourceRecordList": [
              {
                "type": "TestRecord",
                "alertReasonCode": "TESTS",
                "alertReasonDescription": "ACTION LIST HIT - TEST",
                "testSource": "TEST",
                "varListNameFull": "TEST FULL NAME",
                "varListNameShort": "TEST SHORT",
                "varProgList": [
                  "SHORT"
                ],
                "varListId": "3421",
                "subject": {
                  "individual": {
                    "TestScore": {
                      "TestScore": 100,
                      "triggeredRule": "TestRule"
                    },
                    "aNameList": [
                      {
                        "fullName": " TestNameA",
                        "lastName": "TestNameA"
                      },
                      {
                        "firstName": "TestFirst",
                        "fullName": "TestFirst HUSAYN",
                        "lastName": "TestLast"
                      },
                      {
                        "firstName": "TestFirst",
                        "fullName": "TestFull",
                        "lastName": "TestLast"
                      },
                      {
                        "firstName": "TestFirst",
                        "fullName": "TestFull",
                        "lastName": "TestLast"
                      }
                    ],
                    "birthList": [
                      {
                        "dateOfBirth": "12 Apr 1910",
                        "dateOfBirthVerified": "true"
                      }
                    ],
                    "name": {
                      "firstName": "TestFirst",
                      "fullName": "TestFull",
                      "lastName": "TestLast"
                      },
                    "varNationality": [
                      {
                        "verified": "true"
                      }
                    ],
                    "remarks": "remark1"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "testSource": "TEST",
                "varListNameFull": "TEST FULL",
                "varListNameShort": "TEST SHORT",
                "varProgList": [
                  "XYZ"
                ],
                "varListId": "1234",
                "subject": {
                  "individual": {
                    "overallScore": {
                      "TestScore": 100,
                      "triggeredRule": "Testing"
                    },
                    "birthList": [
                      {
                        "dateOfBirth": "1965",
                      },
                      {
                        "dateOfBirth": "1966",
                      }
                    ],
                    "name": {
                      "firstName": "TestFirst",
                      "fullName": "TestFull",
                      "lastName": "TestLast",
                    },
                    "varNationality": [
                      {
                        "verified": "true"
                      }
                    ],
                    "remarks": "REMARK2"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

I need to take response from ""PROCESSConfiguration": {
          "id": 1"
from row # 40. If u'll take above code in notepad ++.

Also I need the response with respect to var value like first name, last name full name, DOB etc.

Comment: Your JSON was mangled when it was posted.  You will want to fix that if you want a specific answer for that data.  You will also want to describe how you want the "nested" values represented in the CSV as CSV is a flat format probably with column headers in this case like firstName, dateOfBirth, and postalCode to name a few.

Comment: I have updated the json format. Also updated the way in whihc I need response.

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure what is being asked for.  Let me assume that you want a fully qualified path for each of the elements in the JSON file.

I started by making some small adjustments to the JSON based on http://jsonlint.com/.

Based on that, I did a proof of concept that works for ONE OBJECT like the JSON you posted.  It works for THIS CASE.  I wrapped the logic to deal with multiple objects making assumptions about when one object started and the next began.  Also, logic would should be added to deal with nested series/array containing multiple properties (i.e. Threads in Get-Process) to handle a generic case.  A single element with an array of values (like .transaction.varProgList in this case) is handled by putting a ‘;’ between them.

CSV files assume that all the objects are symmetric (have the same properties).  There is no check to see that the properties for each object align with the properties of the other objects.  Note the handling of nested series is related to this.  You may see an example of this by uncommenting the [System.Collections.ICollection] section and trying something like `(Get-Process r*) | Select-Object Name,Threads | Expand-NestedProperty | Out-File .\t.csv -Width 100000`

The repro goes as follows where `$a` is the adjusted JSON content and the function is saved as Expand-NestedProperty.ps1.

```
# Load the function
. .\Expand-NestedProperty.ps1
# Create PowerShell object(s) based on the JSON
$b = $a | ConvertFrom-Json 
# Create a file with the CSV contents. 
$b | Expand-NestedProperty | Out-File -FilePath .\my.csv -Width 100000
```

Save this as Expand-NestedProperty.ps1

```
function Expand-NestedProperty {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter( Position=0,
                    Mandatory=$true,
                    ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false,
                    HelpMessage='Object required...' )]
        $InputObject
    )
    begin {
        function ExpandNestedProperty {
            [CmdletBinding()]
            param (
                [Parameter( Position=0,
                            Mandatory=$true,
                            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                            ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false,
                            HelpMessage='Object required...' )]
                $InputObject,
                [Parameter( Position=1,
                            Mandatory=$false,
                            ValueFromPipeline=$false,
                            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                            ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false,
                            HelpMessage='String required...' )]
                [string]
                $FullyQualifiedName = ""
            )
            begin {
                $localResults =@()
                $FQN = $FullyQualifiedName
                $nestedProperties = $null
            }
            process {
                foreach ($obj in $InputObject.psobject.Properties) {
                    if ($(try {$obj.Value[0] -is [PSCustomObject]} catch {$false})) { # Catch 'Cannot index into a null array' for null values
                        # Nested properties
                        $FQN = "$($FullyQualifiedName).$($obj.Name)"
                        $nestedProperties = $obj.value | ExpandNestedProperty -FullyQualifiedName $FQN
                    }
                    elseif ($obj.Value -is [array]) {
                        # Array property
                        $FQN = "$($FullyQualifiedName).$($obj.Name)"
                        [psobject]$nestedProperties = @{
                            $FQN = ($obj.Value -join ';')
                        }
                    }
                    # Example of how to deal with generic case. 
                    # This needed for the Get-Process values ([System.Collections.ReadOnlyCollectionBase] and [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]) that are not [array] collection type.
<#
                    elseif ($obj.Value -is [System.Collections.ICollection]) { 
                        # Nested properties
                        $FQN = "$($FullyQualifiedName).$($obj.Name)"
                        $nestedProperties = $obj.value | ExpandNestedProperty -FullyQualifiedName $FQN
                    }
#>
                    else { # ($obj -is [PSNoteProperty]) for this case, but could be any type
                        $FQN = "$($FullyQualifiedName).$($obj.Name)"
                        [psobject]$nestedProperties = @{
                            $FQN = $obj.Value
                        }
                    }
                    $localResults += $nestedProperties
                } #foreach $obj
            }
            end {
                [pscustomobject]$localResults
            }
        } # function ExpandNestedProperty
        $objectNumber = 0
        $firstObject = @()
        $otherObjects = @()
    }
    process {
        if ($objectNumber -eq 0) {
            $objectNumber++
            $firstObject = $InputObject[0] | ExpandNestedProperty
        }
        else {
            if ($InputObject -is [array]) {
                foreach ($nextInputObject in $InputObject[1..-1]) {
                    $objectNumber++
                    $otherObjects += ,($nextInputObject | ExpandNestedProperty)
                }
            }
            else {
                $objectNumber++
                $otherObjects += ,($InputObject | ExpandNestedProperty)
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        # Output CSV header and a line for each object which was the specific requirement here.  
        # Could create an array of objects using $firstObject + $otherObjects that is then piped to Export-CSV if we want a generic case.
        Write-Output "`"$($firstObject.Keys -join '","')`""
        Write-Output "`"$($firstObject.Values -join '","')`""
        foreach ($otherObject in $otherObjects) {
            Write-Output "`"$($otherObject.Values -join '","')`""
        }
    }
} # function Expand-NestedProperty
```